# Private assets in Play 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

In a Play 2.1 application, where is the proper place to store private assets?

By "private asset", I mean a data file that is used by the application but not accessible to the user.

For example, if I have a text file (`Foo.json`) that contains sample data that is parsed every time the application starts, what would be the proper directory in the project to store it?

`Foo.json` needs to be included in the deployment, and needs to be uniformly accessible from the code in both development and production.

Comment: I'm struggling with similar deployment questions right now, and I'm very interested to hear what the community has to say about this

Answer (score 3):

Some options:

1. Usually the files goes to `conf` folder. ie: `conf/privatefiles/Foo.json`
2. If they are subject of often change you can consider adding to your `application.conf` path to the external folder somwhere in the filesystem (full path), in such case you'll be able to edit the content easily without redeploying the apps: `/home/scrapdog/privatefiles/Foo.json`
3. You can store them in database as well, benefits are the same as in previous option - easy editing.

In all cases consider using memory cache to avoid reading it from filesystem/database every time when required.

Comment: Thanks.  #1 is the only option for me (as the app must be self-contained).  How do I go about uniformly accessing the files (in conf/privatefiles) from the application?

Comment: #1 is kind of a poor solution though, since assets aren't necessarily configuration files

Comment: @cdmckay while OP wants to parse the file at application start only I assume that's just his custom way to configure something...

Comment: So would doing something like `app/assets` still work fine and get packaged?

Answer (score 1):

I simply use a folder called `data` at the application root. You can use the name you want or better, store the actual name in the configuration file.

To resolve its path, I use the following snippet:

```
  lazy val rootPath = {
    import play.api.Play.current
    play.api.Play.application.path.getPath
  }
  lazy val dataPath = rootPath + "/data/"
```

Comment: Is this going to work in production?  i.e., will it package this directory into the jar when I build a dist or deploy to heroku?

Comment: Nope, it will not be packaged in your Jar file. You should go with the first option mentioned by @biesior (put your files in the conf folder).

Comment: @scrapdog I simply use `git` to deploy everything on the production server. If in the future, I would need to build a single jar, I'd move the datafile in a resource directory and use an sbt plugin such as Assembly or Proguard.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what I did, I got the answer from @Marius Soutier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26206759/playframework-were-to-put-files-that-get-rendered-in-views/26216144#26216144). Please upvote his answer there if you like it:

You can put "internal" documents in the `conf` folder, it's the equivalent to `resources` in standard sbt projects.

Basically create a dir under `conf` called `json` and to access it, you'd use `Play.resourceAsStream()`. Note that this gives you a `java.io.InputStream` because your file will be part of the JAR created by `activator dist`.

My example is using it in a view but you can modify it as you want.

```
Play.resourceAsStream("json/Foo.json") map { inputStream =>
  Ok(views.html.xxx(XXX.do_something_with_stream(inputStream)))
} getOrElse (InternalServerError)
```

You can also use `Play.resource()`, this will give you a `java.net.URL`, you can use `getFile()` to get the `java.io.File` out of it.

```
Play.resource("json/Foo.json") map { fileURL =>
  Ok(views.html.xxx(XXX.do_something_with_file(fileURL.getFile())))
} getOrElse (InternalServerError)
```