# Playframework were to put files that get rendered in views

Tags: scala, model-view-controller, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am using the playframework to render Asciidoc text from a file inside my view.
Since that content is used in my view, I want to be able to put it in the `app/views` so it gets packaged when deploying with `activator dist`.

Right now the files get lost after running `activator dist`. Because the content gets rendered by my view I don't want to put in in `public/` or in `app/assets`.

My view looks versy simple:

```
@(html: String)(implicit flash: Flash, lang: Lang)

@main(Messages("application.name")){
  @Html(html)
}
```

And my controller sends the String content to the view:

```
def about = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.statics.normal(Static.render_file("app/views/adoc/about.adoc")))
}
```

Where should I put this file? and how to I access it other than with the path from the root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put "internal" documents in the `conf` folder, it's the equivalent to `resources` in standard sbt projects.

To access it, you'd use `Play.resourceAsStream()`. Note that this gives you an `java.io.InputStream` because your file will be part of the JAR created by `activator dist`.

```
Play.resourceAsStream("adoc/about.adoc") map { adocStream =>
  Ok(views.html.statics.normal(Static.render_file(adocStream)))
} getOrElse (InternalServerError)
```

Comment: Thanks, I edited your answer to add the info about the Play.resource().

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation for managing resources in the `conf` dir? I can't find anything online other than this small little line from the anatomy of a play app `conf                    → Configurations files and other non-compiled resources (on classpath)`.